# How can I write a str object to csv

Tags: python, python-3.x

Specifically, I used pandasql to query a pandas dataframe like this:

```
dataset = "SELECT assetName, universe,volume,returnsClosePrevRaw1 AS Close FROM market ORDER BY assetName DESC LIMIT 5"

print(ps.sqldf(dataset, locals()))
```

The class of "dataset" is str.

I will like to save "dataset" as a csv file to pandas dataframe

Here is a print screen:

[image]

Comment: have you tried `data = pd.read_sql_query(dataset, engine);

data.to_csv('file.csv')` as described in this answer [SQL query output to .csv](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52448387/1248974)

Comment: I have been to find a solution by importing pysqldf from pandasql and using the code:

Comment: great to hear you solved it.

Comment: I have been to find a solution by importing pysqldf from pandasql and using the codes:

pysqldf = lambda q: sqldf(q, globals())

pd.DataFrame(pysqldf("SELECT assetName, universe,volume,returnsClosePrevRaw1 AS Close FROM market ORDER BY assetName DESC;")).to_csv("data1.csv")

Comment: Please [put your solution in an answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and [accept your answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/) so we can close this question and make it available to future readers.

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to find a solution by importing pysqldf from pandasql and using the codes:

p

```
ysqldf = lambda q: sqldf(q, globals()) 

pd.DataFrame(pysqldf("SELECT assetName, universe,volume,returnsClosePrevRaw1 AS Close FROM market ORDER BY assetName DESC;")).to_csv("data1.csv")
```